# disable usercontrol

Tags: .net, asp.net

How to disable a usercontrol so that the Page_Load is not executed ?
Enabled doesn't exist for a usercontrol
and Visible doesn't work, it just hide the usercontrol , but the page load is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

Add this to the top of the page <%@ Reference Control="~/MyControl.ascx" %>

Then when you need the control just add it where you want it like this

ControlPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx"))

This way the control will be only loaded when you need it.

Comment: If you need the ViewState of the disabled user control this is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to remove the control before rendering starts with `this.Controls.Remove(xxx)`
in [preInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) but you would want to make this happen consistently.  E.G. if you remove a control when you first service the request and then let it be enabled on postback you *may* have a problem deserializing viewstate. maybe. is worth a shot